# Why are my reverse SSH tunnels suddenly dying?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

I have had persistent tunnels from all my client computers to my servers in place for about a year now. I've not updated my server or changed any configuration files--as far as I remember--for several months. Suddenly my tunnels stopped working for all of my client computers (I use a different port for each).

I use RSA keys. I've regenerated them multiple times on every computer.

I have a script run the following via a Cron job when it does not find "clients@my.hostname" in "ps aux" output:

```
ssh -p 2222 -g -T -N -x -f -R 2223:localhost:22 clients@my.hostname
```

When I run this command manually with -vvv, I can ssh into the server then ssh into the forwarded port (ssh localhost -p 2223) just fine. After five minutes, however, it just hangs. I get the following output on the server with -vvv:

```
chad@zeus:~$ ssh localhost -p 2223 -vvv
OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu1.2, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 2223.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/chad/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/chad/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/chad/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/chad/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
```

When I telnet to the port I get

```
chad@zeus:~$ telnet localhost 2223
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Normally I get output output like "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3".

On the client side, where I initiated the tunnel (via ssh -p 2222 -g -T -N -x -f -R 2223:localhost:22 clients@my.hostname), I get the following verbose output:

```
OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to my.hostname [68.6.214.39] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/chad/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/chad/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/chad/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/chad/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu1.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu1.2 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 120/256
debug2: bits set: 525/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: put_host_port: [68.6.214.39]:2222
debug3: put_host_port: [my.hostname]:2222
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/chad/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 3
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/chad/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 2
debug1: Host '[my.hostname]:2222' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/chad/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug2: bits set: 534/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/chad/.ssh/id_rsa (0xb9b96ad0)
debug2: key: /home/chad/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/chad/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,gssapi,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/chad/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 14:ff:10:40:31:88:05:bc:46:73:91:ef:58:70:cc:78
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:2223 forwarded to local address localhost:22
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 2223, connect localhost:22
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
```

Permissions for my .ssh directory and files are as follows:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 chad chad   4096 2009-10-15 00:03 .ssh

-rw-r--r-- 1 chad chad  408 2009-10-15 00:03 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 chad chad 1675 2009-10-14 10:09 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 chad chad  393 2009-10-14 10:09 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 chad chad 2210 2009-10-14 11:27 known_hosts
```

Furthermore, if I "killall ssh" on the client and then telnet to port 2223, I still get a response:

```
chad@zeus:~$ telnet localhost 2223
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I am thoroughly confused. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Has there been any change in the network setup around your server?  I've seen this happen when a router or firewall which the traffic goes through does not keep the state of a TCP connection when there's no traffic.

Try adding this to the ssh_config on your server:

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

This will send some data through the ssh connection (It won't interfere with your tunnels) every minute so that whatever might be timing out your connection will not forget about it.  It has the added bonus of killing your ssh tunnels automatically if it's not responsive anymore, which would allow your existing script to reconnect.

Comment: YAY! It seems to be working. Added that to the client ssh_config file. If it continues to work, I'll flag this as the answer. THANKS!

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH...I know what caused this. I changed my router's settings to heavily reduce the timeout settings. I completely forgot about that.

Comment: There's also a ClientAliveInterval directive that works in reverse.  You could put that into your server's sshd_config and get the same effect.

Comment: Early Netgear FVS318 SoHo routers had the same problem, only they were set in the firmware and could not be set in the GUI. Had to be done in the CLI, but the CLI was not accessible because there was no serial on the units our organization purchased.